# How to extract Data from JSP applete page from watir ruby and nokogiri

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, nokogiri, watir-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a form values with ruby , Watir-webdriver and Nokogiri which has some disabled fields.

```
<input type="text" value="Would be auto populated based on Requirement ID" class="form-control" id="SkillId" disabled="disabled" name="SkillId">
```

But in the display it shows the value "**Java, Oracles,Mysql**"

I want to scrap this data i have used the following code

```
doc.at('input[@name="SkillId"]')['value']
```

But it extracts "**Would be auto populated based on Requirement** "

Please help how to extract disabled field Data.

I have tried

```
doc.at('input[@disabled="disabled"]')
```

This gives only disabled field values which has real value but what about when value occurs after removing the disable attribute.

[image]

Comment: How does the "Java, Oracles,Mysql" get displayed? I have only seen text fields display the `value` or `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: Hi Justin see the screenshot i have attached

Comment: this will give you all input which are disabled `doc.at('input[@disabled="disabled"]')`

Comment: That's interesting. Are you sure you are looking at the HTML for the right element? What library is that control being generated by?

Comment: Hi @pradeep this code works but it is extracting only first element.

Comment: and its also not working for text area.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't use screenshots to display HTML or data that would be needed to test your code or to provide an answer. Instead, copy and paste the *minimum* necessary to demonstrate the problem. As is you're making it harder for us to help you, especially when trying to give you an answer specific to the problem. Read "[mcve]" and "[ask]".

Comment: @the Tin Man Solution not worked in my case . Is there any option to remove disabled attribute with nokogiri

Comment: @ Pardeep Dhingra

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about extracting information from tags/fields which change using DHTML. Nokogiri isn't able to help you unless you can capture that HTML _after_ the DHTML has modified it. Turn off JavaScript in your browser and look at the page, or use `nokogiri your_url` or `wget your_url` at the command-line and see if you can find the information. If not then there's DHTML afoot, modifying the content after the browser has loaded it.

Comment: actually page is using Java applet may be and after loading the content. in html there is no output while in browser it shows data.is it possible to extract ?

Comment: @ the Tin Man please see the above screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="foo">
      <input name="bar" disabled>
      <button disabled>Foo</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('[disabled]').map(&:to_html) # => ["<input name=\"bar\" disabled>", "<button disabled>Foo</button>"]
```

That searches for all tags with a `disabled` parameter.

```
doc.search('input[disabled]').map(&:to_html) # => ["<input name=\"bar\" disabled>"]
```

That searches for only `<input>` tags with a `disabled` parameter.

Comment: Hi this only shows disabled fields . I want the values in the disabled field .<input type=\"text\" value=\"Would be auto populated based on Requirement ID\> . I want to extract values . as previous solution doc.at('input[@disabled="disabled"]') this gives value of requirement id. I want to extract all values like this.

Comment: The solution puts you on top of how to get the data you want. Stack Overflow isn't a "write code for me site" it's to show you how to do things. It's still up to you to read the documentation and research additional things you can do. There are *MANY* other questions on SO showing how to extract a particular parameter's value once you know the node.

Comment: after searching most of question i have posted this question . no issue i am trying again to find some thing which will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
doc.at('input[@disabled="disabled"]')
```

Comment: but it works for only first element . can you suggest how to extract other elements.

Comment: When answering, please don't toss out just code. Explain why it works and why it should be used. We want to help people learn, not just solve the immediate problem.